# BJT selection for the reference circuit

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, analog, bjt, analog-switch

I have simulated the below circuit in LTspice and found that the BJT (Q203) is having less power dissipation (~1mW) then the Q202 BJT.
However, the designer selected a 200mW package for the Q203 and 100mW for the Q202.

Can anyone help me understand what am I missing here? As per my understanding even if I select the same 100mW BJT part for both of them then also the circuit will be okay as per the LTspice simulations.

In scenario 1, When Motor is ON, Q203 (ON), Q202 (OFF)

In scenario 2, When Motor is OFF Q203 (OFF), Q202 (ON)

Q202 MPN: RN1102

Q203 MPN: RN1402

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: I can't read minds and don't have a working crystal ball, besides. There can be many reasons why BJTs are specified. The only thing we know, assuming your simulation results accurately reflect the designer's work product, is that the packages appear dissipate orders of magnitude more power than actually required. Which suggests that wasn't an issue in the decision.